# Maven pom: soft vs hard version requirement specification

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

In Maven [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), under the [Dependency version requirement specification](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification) chapter, a difference is made between *soft* and *hard* requirements:

> 1.0: "Soft" requirement on 1.0 (just a recommendation, if it matches all other ranges for the dependency)
>   [1.0]: "Hard" requirement on 1.0

So if I write:

```
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

I'm expressing a *soft* requirement, while with:

```
<version>[1.0.0]</version>
```

I'm requiring a hard one.

While I understand all the other version specifiers explained (well explained in [this](/q/30571/3127111) question too), I can't get this difference.

I guess that a hard requirement means: if there's no `1.0.0` version available, that dependency can't be satisfied; but what's a soft one? Does it mean that even `1.0` or `1.0.0.1` would fit for that dependency? Or is the meaning totally different?

Note: I always use soft dependency specifications, I'm asking because I'm interested in understanding the difference, rather than choosing between using one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a runtime dependency in your project Maven needs to decide which version should be used. Ideally the artifact with the declared version number is available and that's it.

But often you depend on several dependencies. And these dependencies themselves depend on other dependencies (thats called '[transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)'). In this case it can happen, that a dependency (e.g. a logging framework) is requested from different libraries in different versions. Maven has to "resolve" the dependencies in this case (to avoid having the same libraries in different versions on the classpath). To do so Maven follows a strategy and "recommended" versions may be overruled by other versions because of the dependency resolution strategy (see example [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)).

But I guess Maven will only overrule "soft" versions and not the "hard" ones. Thus if you have two different "hard" versions in your dependency tree, a conflict resolution will not be possible and the buid will fail.

From my experience I can tell you that "hard" version numbers are very rarely used (I do not know any example by now). Just go with a dedicated "soft" version and do not use a version range (this will make your build not reproducable any more).

---

By the way, you can find a quite similar explanation in the Sonatype Book: **Maven: The Complete Reference** - Chapter 3.4.3: [Dependency Version Ranges](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges)

> When declaring a "normal" version such as 3.8.2 for Junit, internally
>   this is represented as "allow anything, but prefer 3.8.2." This means
>   that when a conflict is detected, Maven is allowed to use the conflict
>   algorithms to choose the best version. If you specify [3.8.2], it
>   means that only 3.8.2 will be used and nothing else. If somewhere else
>   there is a dependency that specifies [3.8.1], you would get a build
>   failure telling you of the conflict.

Comment: instead of guessing, wouldn't it be quite easy to test what happens?

Comment: I'm not looking for suggestions about which one I should use; I've edited my questions, thanks for making me aware of that.

Comment: Forget my recommendation - this was just bonus ;-). I think I explained the rest ("soft" means overrulable) and yes - it should be easy to test.